# php not getting back to line in file

Tags: php

well, here is my PHP code:

```
 $file = fopen("mon_fichier.txt","a+");
    fputs($file, "\n");
    fputs($file, "kodsi");
    fputs($file, "\n");
    fclose($file);
```

then I go the file to see that there was no getting back to line: the \n is not working.

Comment: I think it's `\r\n`, do `PHP_EOL` isntead of `\n`

Comment: What OS is this running off of?

Comment: That's a Unix-style line feed. The only conceivable way in which it cannot work is to use a poorly written text viewer in a Windows computer, e.g. Windows Notepad.

Comment: I have test your script and on my server it works well.

Comment: windows, \*NIX, mac ?? did you leave the question? I asked which OS earlier.

Comment: @ Fred -ii- windows 10

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should have a look at what are line endings depending on OS
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

In fact, you would have to replace your \n by \r\n

Comment: thank you guys for the help, i tried \r\n and it works

Comment: @AbdElKodousSouissi, could you please mark you question as answered?